# Argument of type '"Page Not Found 404"' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ error: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this code

```
function App() {
  const [prod, setProd] = useState(Object);
  const [resError, setResError] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const searchParams = await new URLSearchParams(match.params.product);
        if (!searchParams.get("Length")) {
          throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
        }
        const Length = await `${searchParams.get("Length")}`;
        const res = await fetch(`......`);
        const product = await res.json();
        setProd(product);

      } catch (error) {
        setResError(error.message);
      }
    })();
  }, [match]);

  if (resError !== "") {
    return <Error error={resError} />;
  } else return (<Prod prod={prod}/>)
}
```

in line

```
 if (!searchParams.get("Length")) {
          throw new Error("Page Not Found 404");
        }
```

I check for null.But for some reason I get this error.Argument of type '"Page Not Found 404"' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ error: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a component called 'Error' in your file. 
So, you are trying to throw a react component, which doesn't make sense. You just need to import it with different name or better change your component name to ErrorView

change

```
import { Error } from '.......error'

<your code>
```

into

```
import { Error as ErrorView } from '.......error'

<your code>
```

Comment: Name conflict as always Thanks.